# Why would Amazon allow my book to be published in Dutch

Tags: translation

Not sure how it happened. Found out when I received a link and discovered it has been translated. I am not sure who, when, or how the translation occurred. Is this normal practice?

Comment: Did you self-publish?  Your publisher probably has the right to translate if not.  If so, you may be dealing with piracy.

Comment: Please add some more details to your question: Did you self-publish? What service did you use? What do their TOS say? If you published with a publisher, what does your contract say? Who is the publisher of the translated book? Is it published under your name?

Comment: is the book published under your account? If not, you've been pirated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking about a book you published yourself. [You can find the current Kindle Direct Publishing terms and conditions here](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G200627430) and check them yourself, but I can't find anything in them that allows Amazon to alter your work in any way, including translating it. That would also be a major challenge to copyright law.

IP Watchdog says, "A translation is what’s known as a derivative work. For a derivative work, [only the copyright owner, who is usually the author, can authorize a translation to be distributed or not](https://ipwatchdog.com/2021/11/03/copyright-translated-content-creator/id=139477). A derivative work will be considered to be a copyright infringement if it was not authorized by the copyright owner." [Amazon's Kindle program is very clear that you're the copyright owner of your own books](https://selfpublishingadvice.org/prove-your-publishing-rights/).

The Kindle Direct Publishing content guidelines provide a lot of information how YOU can get YOUR book translated in order to sell it in other markets. There is, however, absolutely nothing anywhere that suggests that you could grab ANOTHER author's book, get it translated, and sell it without their knowledge or permission.

It's also pretty expensive to get a book professionally translated. It's absolutely possible that someone got software to rip the text of your ebook, threw it into some kind of cheap translation software, and put it up on Kindle themselves - possibly along with many other books, as a get-cash-quick side business.

If you [go to the various Amazon sites for the Netherlands, France, Japan, etc](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G200672400)., and check each one for pirated versions of your work, you can report them. I believe Amazon is supposed to take the pirated work down and give you any money it made.

The American one is https://www.amazon.com/report/infringement, and it looks like you can just change the subdomain to make a report on the different sites: https://www.amazon.nl/report/infringement, https://www.amazon.jp/report/infringement, etc. (However, you have to create a new Amazon account for each one, which is annoying.)